# How to prevent default listview click in jquery mobile?

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

i create one listview..In listview i put one button..like

```
<ul class="ui-listview">
 <li>
  <p>HEllo</p>
  <input type='button' id='btn1'>
  </li>

<li>
  <p>Hiii</p>
  <input type='button' id='btn2'>
  </li>
</ui>
```

Now i want click event of this button and stop default click of listview...so hows its possible in jquery ?

Comment: [`event.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)?

Comment: [`event.stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), [`event.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: In your button click event handler I assume `$("#btn1").click(function(event){...});`

Comment: But then again in your example `li`s are not clickable because you don't have links in them, so why bother? Or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input[type=button]").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    //your code goes here
});
```

[Here is jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/GLWQw/) based on your markup.